# SQLite3::SQLException when using database_cleaner with Rails / Spork / RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rspec, spork

When attempting to follow example on database_cleaner's [GitHub page](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner#rspec-example), I encountered the following error from RSpec:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction: begin transaction
```

The configuration used in spec_helper.rb is:

```
require 'spork'
require 'database_cleaner'

Spork.prefork do
 # .. snip
  RSpec.configure do |config|
   # .. snip
    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end
end

Spork.each_run do

end
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error while creating a record, may be you can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367396/sql-error-cannot-start-a-transaction-within-a-transaction-while-testing-with-cuc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to be changing the entire strategy to `:truncation`. Updated spec_helper:

```
require 'spork'
require 'database_cleaner'

Spork.prefork do

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

  end
end

Spork.each_run do

end
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer makes all tests slower (when it's not needed) by truncating after each one.

Just add

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

when using database_cleaner.

If you have both `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` and `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction` you're going to start a transaction inside another transaction and that's not allowed.

Comment: Been a while since I had this issue. I think I may have tried that. Forget which project, so I can't re-test =\

Comment: @Dan I thought that may have happened, but I answered to keep a record for future readers.